# Android APK installation failed even after uninstalling old apk

Tags: java, android, android-studio

This is what I get when I try to run my app. I dont know what this means but it won't go away and the original app is uninstalled too.
[image]

This is what i see in the run monitor when i click ok.

`$ adb install-multiple -r C:\Users\sherry\Desktop\Pocketsphynx\pocketSphin_Youtube\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_8.apk C:\Users\sherry\Desktop\Pocketsphynx\pocketSphin_Youtube\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_9.apk C:\Users\sherry\Desktop\Pocketsphynx\pocketSphin_Youtube\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_7.apk C:\Users\sherry\Desktop\Pocketsphynx\pocketSphin_Youtube\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_0.apk C:\Users\sherry\Desktop\Pocketsphynx\pocketSphin_Youtube\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\dep\dependencies.apk C:\Users\sherry\Desktop\Pocketsphynx\pocketSphin_Youtube\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_5.apk C:\Users\sherry\Desktop\Pocketsphynx\pocketSphin_Youtube\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_6.apk C:\Users\sherry\Desktop\Pocketsphynx\pocketSphin_Youtube\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_4.apk C:\Users\sherry\Desktop\Pocketsphynx\pocketSphin_Youtube\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_1.apk C:\Users\sherry\Desktop\Pocketsphynx\pocketSphin_Youtube\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_2.apk C:\Users\sherry\Desktop\Pocketsphynx\pocketSphin_Youtube\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_3.apk C:\Users\sherry\Desktop\Pocketsphynx\pocketSphin_Youtube\build\outputs\apk\pocketSphin_Youtube-debug.apk 
$ adb shell pm uninstall com.qolbotics.pocketsphinx_sample
Unknown failure (at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:565))
Error while Installing APKs`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the same when used emulator. If it was on emulator try on real device. 
Matching abis issue is related to the compiler (arm or dalvik) it means that you have some native libraries that haven't their appropriate architecture, for example in emulator it's an Intel architecture and on real device an arm architecture.

Answer (score 1):

Got the same when used emulator. If it was on emulator try on real device. 
Matching abis issue is related to the compiler (arm or dalvik) try also to install missing arm libraries from SDK

Comment: cheers bud, it works on my phone. I'm a newbie at this so could you possibily give me a reference as to how i would go about installing the missing arm libraries, and thanks for the help.

Comment: I&#39;ve edited my answer, because the previous one was not sent completely, try to add the according Intel arm libraries in SDK manager. Let me know if you don&#39;t succeed

Try the Intel x86 one

Answer (score 0):

I had similar kind of an issue which was resolved by simply doing "clean project" from build menu. Its worth a try.